# Nest multiple components on the same route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes defined

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/' component={Landing}>
      <Route path='' component={Invitation}/>
      <Route path='signin' component={Signin}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NoMatch}/>
  </Router>
);
```

I would like that when visiting the root `/` route, that the `Invitation` component gets rendered inside the `Landing` component, but I havent found a way to do this without using a nested route/url

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best to achieve it, is to use the IndexRoute, which requires nesting too, but is especially designed for your use-case I think.

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/' component={Landing}>
      <IndexRoute component={Invitation}/>
      <Route path='signin' component={Signin}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NoMatch}/>
  </Router>
);
```

See documentation:
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/IndexRoutes.md